# How to iterate a list of dictionaries to a desired format for API consumption

Tags: list

```
Please guys,How do I iterate this list and group some keys and values based on common keys
```

and values using python?

I have a Jsonresponse that needs to be consumed by an API in a strutured order. I have looked
up this platform and have seen many examples and have tried most of them to no avail and have
decided to bring the problem down here for you guys to help me out. I am new to python.

```
input
[
    {"id": "3", "name": "John",
        "team": "corinthians", "coach": "Chris"},
    {"id": "2", "name": "Ben",
     "team": "palmeiras", "coach": "Aron"},
    {"id": "6", "name": "Frank",
     "team": "palmeiras", "coach": "Aron"}, 
    {"id": "7", "name": "Evan",
     "team": "corinthians", "coach": "Chris"}, 
    {"id": "1", "name": "Micheal",
     "team": "palmeiras", "coach": "Aron"},
    {"id": "10", "name": "Zack",
     "team": "santos", "coach": "David"}

] 

Expected output

The players are grouped by their team and coach reducing the need of repeating a player to the same  team and coach every time.

I need to present the data in this format.kindly help me out guys.Thanks

[{"players": 
            [{"id": "3", "name": "John"}, {"id": "7", "name": "Evan"}], "team": "corinthians",
"coach": "Chris"},
        {"players": [{"id": "2", "name": "Ben"}, {"id": "6", "name": "Frank"}, {"id": "1", 
"name": "Micheal"}], "team": "palmeiras", "coach": "Aron"}, 
        {"players": [{"id": "10", "name": "Zack"}], "team": "santos", "coach": "David"}]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code will save the output you want in the `result` variable.

```
input = [
    {"id": "3", "name": "John",
        "team": "corinthians", "coach": "Chris"},
    {"id": "2", "name": "Ben",
     "team": "palmeiras", "coach": "Aron"},
    {"id": "6", "name": "Frank",
     "team": "palmeiras", "coach": "Aron"}, 
    {"id": "7", "name": "Evan",
     "team": "corinthians", "coach": "Chris"}, 
    {"id": "1", "name": "Micheal",
     "team": "palmeiras", "coach": "Aron"},
    {"id": "10", "name": "Zack",
     "team": "santos", "coach": "David"}]

result = []
teamsAdded = set()
for player in input:
    if (player['team'] not in teamsAdded):
        teamsAdded.add(player['team'])
        result.append({"team": player['team'], "coach": player['coach'], "players": [{"id": player['id'], "name": player['name']}]})
    else:
        for team in result:
            if team['team'] == player['team']:
                team['players'].append({"id": player['id'], "name": player['name']})
```

Comment: Thank you so much @Tyler Liu.you solved the problem for me. I am really grateful.

Comment: I now have another doubt @Tyler Liu. What if the coach could coach more than a team, how could i represent that? Thanks in advance.

Comment: I believe it would still be correct in that case. I changed the coach of "santos" to Aron, and it looks like the output is correct. 

If you found my original answer useful, please consider upvoting and marking it as accepted.